# how to compare between between m.author and member.id? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

```
@client.command()
async def marry(ctx, member:discord.Member):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="زواج", description=f"{member.mention} هل توافق على الزواج من {ctx.message.author.mention}؟", color=0xc91313)
    embed.set_author(name="شيخ المافيا", url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/707638848225542290/820740161859092520/STK-20200526-WA0007.webp", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/707638848225542290/820740161859092520/STK-20200526-WA0007.webp")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=member.guild, icon_url=member.guild.icon_url)
    if member == ctx.message.author:
        await ctx.send('لا يمكنك الزواج من نفسك!')
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} اذا كنت موافقا على الزواج ارسل كلمة `اوافق`.')
        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'smth' and 
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await ctx.send(f'مبروك الزواج {member.mention} و {ctx.message.author.mention}')
```

sorry for the language but i want the bot responses only on the mentioned member
not any one who writes smth

Answer (score 0):

`m.author.id`? Have you tried that? It's simple logic really... Or you can simply do `m.author == member`

```py
def check(m):
    return m.content == "smth" and m.author == member # or m.author.id == member.id
```